# Grid autofit last item goes above instead of below

Tags: css, sass, grid

Im trying to flexbox-wrap reverse in grid but struggling. Is there anyway to do this with grid?

regular screen view:

```
1 2
```

on collapse according to min-width:

```
1

2
```

what I want:

```
2

1
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @cookiewaffles In media query change order of the item.

Comment: if the duplicates did not answer your exact same answer of yesterday, please clarify,  add what you tried and did not work